# Employing a proxy in Remoting Concept

Tags: c#, remoting

I am a newbie in remoting concepts(C# Remoting).Actually i done some projects using 
remoting concepts, i need to employ a proxy between the client and server , if client
wants to communicate with the server or vice-versa it should be done through this proxy
only.i saw a namespace Remoting.Proxy ,will it help? anyone giveme some suggestions on
how to do this it will be very useful for me.

I heard that if the request is through proxy it will be more secure.if my server address is(182.575.069.67) and my proxy runs in 192.168.0.8 then all my clients must send their messages to the proxy and the proxy server must forward this to the actual server.This is what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

The "Proxy" namespace refers to the idea that there needs to be a local object, working en-proxy for the remoting client.

If you need all traffic to the server to go through a proxy, you should create two executables: the server, and the proxy server.

The server could accept requests only from the proxy service, while the proxy service itself could be promiscuous.

However, I'm not sure why you would need to set up a proxy service, since you should be able to put any of your autorization / authentication code directly into the server service anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies in C# (especially in the System.Remoting namespace) are local, in-process objects that *represent* an object in a different process.

They're named after the Proxy Object pattern, not after proxy servers.